# $\Sigma_*$ in Gaussian Process Prediction Formula

Tags: probability, gaussian-process, kernel-trick

So posterior predictive distribution of the Gaussian process is given by the following equation.

$\mathbf{f}_*$ given new input $\mathbf{X}_*:$

$$p(\mathbf{f}_* \lvert \mathbf{X}_*,\mathbf{X},\mathbf{y}) 
= \int{p(\mathbf{f}_* \lvert \mathbf{X}_*,\mathbf{f})p(\mathbf{f} \lvert \mathbf{X},\mathbf{y})}\ d\mathbf{f} \\ 
= \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{f}_* \lvert \boldsymbol{\mu}_*, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_*)$$

What I would like to ask is what is $\Sigma_*$ here? it was not defined in this [post](http://krasserm.github.io/2018/03/19/gaussian-processes/) I read.

Comment: Check Eq (5) in that post?

Comment: Ok, I got what is it defined. But what is it called?

Comment: $\Sigma$ is convention notation for covariance matrix in multivariate normal distribution, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution. $\Sigma_*$ is used to denote "new covariance matrix" or "derived covariance matrix" I guess.

Comment: ok so to clarify it is covariace and not variance?

Comment: Because in most common multivariate normal distribution parameterization,  $N(\mu,\Sigma)$, $\mu$ is called *expectation* and $\Sigma$ is called *covariance matrix*. You can read "Conditional distributions" section in wikipedia to figure out how that post derived Eq (4) (5).